# How do I match framerates between a VideoCapture and VideoWriter in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, video, video-streaming

UPDATE: Based on feedback from this site and others, it appears OpenCV is not a great platform for subtleties of video recording (like frame-rate issues).

I have two threads running in a C++ OpenCV3.4 app. One thread reads frames in a loop with `VideoCapture` and writes them to a `boost::circular_buffer`. The other thread pulls the frames out of the buffer and writes them to `VideoWriter`.

Here's the problem: The camera is 29.97fps, but the loop doesn't read that fast because it is a slow CPU. It averages 10-15fps. This framerate fluctuates so I cannot just set the `VideoWriter` to 10fps and carry on, because I encounter buffer over/underflow based on other things happening in the system.

Do I have to manually track both framerates, and drop/resend frames to the `VideoWriter` to maintain an expected FPS rate, or is there already a way to manage this in OpenCV that I am missing?

Thanks,
PT

Comment: Invest in a CPU that can keep up with the work? There's nothing to manage this sort of issue already in OpenCV. Frankly, if you're after performance in resource-poor environment, I'd ditch `VideoCapture` and see if I can access the camera directly (and have full control over what's happening). It's just too much of a black bock, trying fit dozens of different backends into one common interface.

Comment: Thanks, but performance isn't the issue, and cannot be addressed because the platform is fixed: this is an engineering problem, not an accounting one. Frames can be duplicated or dropped depending on the camera/CPU bottleneck, that's one way to solve it by monitoring the average error (can't adapt the bitrate.) However, I'm asking if there is an **OpenCV** solution built-in there somewhere in the VideoWriter that isn't well documented perhaps.

Comment: afaik, openCV's VideoWriter is too limited. Try a library that can handle video file writing with timestamps. Probably ffmpeg can.